# Associations ONLY work with $scaffold

Tags: cakephp

New to Cake, and trying to set up model associations.  I'm creating an execution planner, to be used by multiple teams, aka 'groups' where the base unit of a plan is an 'event'.  Each event is owned by one team, but it can have many supporting teams.

When I use $scaffold in the controllers, the model associations work as expected and when adding a new event I get a select box with all the groups to select who owns an event. However, when I bake the controller using console, the select box for `group_id` is blank.  I've included the baked `add()` code from the controller, and from the baked add view.  I also tried `debug($this)` in `add.ctp`, and found that the list of groups is indeed being passed to the view.  I'm thus mostly confused about why it works with $scaffold, but not otherwise.

Any advice or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

**Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(5) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Group that owns event',
  `version` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `stime` time NOT NULL,
  `etime` time NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events_groups` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `liveversion` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `lastupdated` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

**Models:**

Event:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Prigroup' => array(
        'className' => 'Group',
        'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
        )
    );


public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Secgroup' => array(
        'className' => 'Group',
        'joinTable' => 'events_groups',
        'foreignKey' => 'event_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'group_id',
    )
);
```

Group:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Prievent' => array(
        'className' => 'Event',
        'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
        )
    );

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Secevent' => array(
        'className' => 'Event',
        'joinTable' => 'events_groups',
        'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'event_id',
    )
);
```

**EventsController Snippet:**

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Event->create();
        if ($this->Event->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The event could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $prigroups = $this->Event->Prigroup->find('list');
    $secgroups = $this->Event->Secgroup->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('prigroups', 'secgroups'));
}
```

**Add view:**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Event'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Event'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('group_id');
        echo $this->Form->input('version');
        echo $this->Form->input('type');
        echo $this->Form->input('stime');
        echo $this->Form->input('etime');
        echo $this->Form->input('description');
        echo $this->Form->input('comment');
        echo $this->Form->input('Secgroup');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

**Add HTML Output**

```
<div class="input select"><label for="EventGroupId">Group</label><select name="data[Event][group_id]" id="EventGroupId">
</select></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u try something for me please? Rename the $prigroups variable to "groups" and pass it to the view. See if this is working. Otherwise use this one with your old code:

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'group_id',
    array(
        'options' => $prigroups
    )
);
```

I also recommend you to use camel case for all those PriGroups and SecGroups. Those are two words in english so camel case advisable.

Greetings
func0der

Comment: Renaming prigroups to groups indeed does work. Weird. Would you be able to explain why? Does that suggest there is something wrong in my Event model? Also, good point on camel casing. They actually were originally camel cased, but I removed it while trying to find the source of my problem. TIA.

Comment: I think this is because cake uses the model name as a base for searches for appropriate field types and/or predefined option values. This is because almost everything is based on model names in cake and everything gets pluralized based on them.
Based on the fact you are using two times the same model for associations i would recommend you to use the method provided above in case you want to use different groups for the association.
And keep an eye on the fact that a supportive group should not be a primary group while validation and/or editing ;)

Comment: First thanks for your explanation, I understand it as you've written, but it basically creates new questions.  For example, in Event model, should I do away with `PriGroup` and call the belongsTo association `Group` and the HABTM `SecGroup`?  Also, since I use two associations from Group-->Event, should I also change the `PriEvent` & `SecEvent` names to `Event` & `SecEvent` to avoid problems there down the road?  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You index name would make no difference to it at all, because it is always the same model. Also a group can have more than one primary event, right?
What I would properbly do is: get rid of those additional $belongsTo associations. Just use the HABTM with an additional field in the association table called for example "primary" or stuff like that. For the association i'd use an extra model to have the most of all flexibility. You'll find some information to that method here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm (ff).